# IUrlHelper.Action() returns null for Delete() action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm struggling to understand the `IUrlHelper.Action()` method. I created a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API and added a `Get()` and `Delete()` action method to `WeatherForecastController` (you can ignore the implementation):

```cs
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("2")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)],

            // see here
            Get = Url.Action(nameof(WeatherForecastController.Get), "WeatherForecast", new { id = 1 }, "https"),
            Delete = Url.Action(nameof(WeatherForecastController.Delete), "WeatherForecast", new { id = 1 }, "https"),
        })
        .ToArray();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Ok(Enumerable.Range(1, 1).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray());
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

As you can see I also added API versioning. The `Startup` is as follows:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services
            .AddApiVersioning(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultApiVersion = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiVersion(1, 0);
                options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                options.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
                options.ErrorResponses = new ApiVersioningErrorResponseProvider();
                options.RegisterMiddleware = true;
                options.ReportApiVersions = true;
            })
            .AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
            {
                options.GroupNameFormat = "VVV";
                options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
            });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

When calling `api/v2/WeatherForcast` I get the following result:

```json
[
    {
        "date": "2020-10-31T09:30:07.8675547+01:00",
        "temperatureC": -3,
        "temperatureF": 27,
        "summary": "Chilly",
        "get": "https://localhost:44302/api/v2/WeatherForecast/1",
        "delete": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-11-01T09:30:07.8989581+01:00",
        "temperatureC": -2,
        "temperatureF": 29,
        "summary": "Freezing",
        "get": "https://localhost:44302/api/v2/WeatherForecast/1",
        "delete": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-11-02T09:30:07.8990626+01:00",
        "temperatureC": 26,
        "temperatureF": 78,
        "summary": "Balmy",
        "get": "https://localhost:44302/api/v2/WeatherForecast/1",
        "delete": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-11-03T09:30:07.8990829+01:00",
        "temperatureC": 24,
        "temperatureF": 75,
        "summary": "Scorching",
        "get": "https://localhost:44302/api/v2/WeatherForecast/1",
        "delete": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-11-04T09:30:07.8991014+01:00",
        "temperatureC": 52,
        "temperatureF": 125,
        "summary": "Balmy",
        "get": "https://localhost:44302/api/v2/WeatherForecast/1",
        "delete": null
    }
]
```

Can somebody explain why the `"delete"` property is `null`? I fail to see any reason, why `"delete"` should not contain the same link as `"get"`. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, the delete URL is not null, when I remove all API versioning stuff, but I can't explain why...

Comment: I have also created a test demo on my side and I removed the AddVersionedApiExplorer and I could get the delete value. Is there special setting or else you have set in it?

Comment: Removing AddVersionedApiExplorer() only has no effect for me ("delete" is still null).

Comment: Also I removed the  `options.ErrorResponses = new ApiVersioningErrorResponseProvider()` since I don't know your codes.

Comment: My code is exactly what you see in the question above with additional properties called Get and Delete inside the WeatherForecast class. Removing `options.ErrorResponses = ...` and `AddVersionedApiExplorer()` have no effect for me. Only removing all api versioning stuff inside `Startup` and `WeatherForecastController` made the delete url work until now

Comment: I still couldn't reproduce your issue on my side.  Could you please share AddVersionedApiExplorer and ApiVersioningErrorResponseProvider codes?

Comment: Thanks for your trouble. You can see the AddVersionedApiExplorer code in the original question above. The ApiVersioningErrorResponseProvider class used is from the ApiVersioning package and was not written by me (I am using package version 4.1.1 btw). In the meantime, I have asked [a similar question](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/688) on the GitHub repo of the package. A solution to my problem would be using version 4.2.0, which was released a few hours ago.